# Android - Adjust the Height of ViewPager for each child

Tags: android, slideshow, pager

Are there any ways to adjust the height of viewpager on runtime?
I tried this
first child:

```
pager.getLayoutParams().height=250;
```

second child:

```
pager.getLayoutParams().height=850;
```

But it doesn't work.
Are there any better ways to create a slideshow like the viewpager with layouts of different heights?

Comment: post your entire code where you used those code above

Comment: you need to set the height after the request layout has been called. You can use viewtreeobserver or just handler.postdealyed to set the height

Comment: I used ScrollView in ViewPager and it is fine too.